# Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled: application.css

Tags: heroku, rspec, assets, circleci, ruby-on-rails-6

I get the following error when running my rspec test on CircleCI or Heroku Integration testing. However, it does not appear when running locally.

```
--- Caused by: ---

     # Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled:

     #   application.css
```

I tried adding:

I tried adding `config.assets.debug = false` to my test environment, but still fails on Heroku and CircleCI, but passes locally.

I found the following:

https://github.com/phfdonda/story-weavers/pull/2

https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphiql-rails/issues/75

https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/633

https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/690

My manifest file is:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link application.css
//= link application.js
```

adding a precompile in the test environment does not fix the issue..

```
 config.assets.precompile += ['application.js', 'application.css']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out I needed to add the following to my circleci config file:

```
  - run:
      name: Precompile Assets
      command: bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and similar for heroku..

https://www.dwightwatson.com/posts/rails-with-webpacker-on-heroku-ci